# Remove double quotes from JSON string value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, geojson

I create a JSON string whith dynamical values which looks like this:

```
{"geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": ["78.454", "22.643"]}, "type": "Feature", "properties": {"Number":"123","Plate":"xxx","Position":"xyz",}}
```

the dynamical values are the coordinates and the values in the properties.

the code to create the string is the following:

```
var tmpLlrtArr = [];
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
var tmpLlrtObj = {};
            tmpLlrtObj.type = 'Feature';
            tmpLlrtObj.geometry = {};
            tmpLlrtObj.geometry = {};
            tmpLlrtObj.geometry.type = 'Point';
            tmpLlrtObj.geometry.coordinates = [(value.longitude_mdeg * 0.000001).toFixed(6), (value.latitude_mdeg * 0.000001).toFixed(6)];
            tmpLlrtObj.properties = {};
            tmpLlrtObj.properties.Number = value.objectno;
            tmpLlrtObj.properties.Plate = value.objectname;
            tmpLlrtObj.properties.Position = value.postext_short;

            tmpLlrtArr.push(tmpLlrtObj);
});

var llrealTimeJSONString = JSON.stringify(llrealTimeObj);
    console.log(llrealTimeObj);
```

know I have the problem that, the coordinates are under double quotes and I have no idea how to remove only them.

the possible solutions here on stack overflow doesn't work for me.
has anybody an advice for me?

Comment: Your JSON is valid; the quotes are fine. You don't need to remove them. Unless you mean that you want to convert the values from string to floating point numbers...?

Comment: The coordinates are strings because you used `toFixed()`, which has to return a string (numbers don't have a specific number of digits).

Comment: You can call `parseFloat()` to turn them back into floating point numbers, but then they might get extra digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of [`toFixed(6)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) to stop converting the numbers to String:

```
var tmpLlrtArr = [];
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
var tmpLlrtObj = {};
            tmpLlrtObj.type = 'Feature';
            tmpLlrtObj.geometry = {};
            tmpLlrtObj.geometry = {};
            tmpLlrtObj.geometry.type = 'Point';
            tmpLlrtObj.geometry.coordinates = [(value.longitude_mdeg * 0.000001), (value.latitude_mdeg * 0.000001)];
            tmpLlrtObj.properties = {};
            tmpLlrtObj.properties.Number = value.objectno;
            tmpLlrtObj.properties.Plate = value.objectname;
            tmpLlrtObj.properties.Position = value.postext_short;

            tmpLlrtArr.push(tmpLlrtObj);
});

var llrealTimeJSONString = JSON.stringify(llrealTimeObj);
    console.log(llrealTimeObj);
```